# Should it be のにです or ですのに when stating an omitted 2nd sentence in polite sentence?

Tags: grammar, particles

In polite sentences when the 2nd sentence is omitted, should the です be before or after the particles?

> A: 彼女はいつも勉強しません。

which one should B say?

> B: 学生なのにです。

or

> B: 学生ですのに。

---

> A: お金はありませんのか。

which one should B answer?

> B: 学生なのでです。

or

> B: 学生ですので。

(Feel free to correct any wrong grammar in either B or A. If no one points it out, I'll assume I am right.)

The real question is the position of です. ので indicates reason for the 2nd sentence and のに means despite. And in plain sentences the です is omitted. Am I right guys (for the facts I have shown)?

Comment: `お金はありませんのか。` -> Probably you meant to say 「お金がないのですか。」, no?

Comment: You're right! Thx for pointing that out! Btw can I say お金はないんですか。using the topic particle instead of the subject one?

Comment: Yes, お金はないんですか is also a grammatical and natural sentence. But お金がないんですか and お金はないんですか have different meanings/nuances, so you'd use them in different contexts. For example, you'd say お金はないんですか to mean "Don't you have money? (though I think you should)", and お金がないんですか to mean "(What's wrong?) Is it that you have no money?" or "(You look troubled.) Is it because you have no money?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

学生なのにです is natural in the first example. I rarely hear 学生ですのに but couth ladies may say that.

お金はありませんのか is unnatural. お金を(orは)持っていませんか、お金を(orは)持っていますか, お金はありますか are appropriate. 学生ですので is natural. 学生なのでです is unnatural but 学生なので(持って)ないです is natural.

Comment: what if the reason is not a state of being but a verb. Using ので, omitting the result, and in polite form... Should it be 食べるのでです or 食べるので

Comment: As I said, we don't say のでてす but からです. You can say 食べるからです.

Comment: A:パーティに行きませんか。B:勉強するからです。so we can't use ので in this case? Since 勉強するので is plain form. If A and B speak in plain form, then it's possible?

Comment: The answer 勉強するからです for パーティに行きませんか is unnatural. It is said to questions like なぜ、今日はバーティーに行かないんですか? . パーティに行きませんか means "invitation" . からです is used for the reason but I think if the end is ので and から like 勉強するのでand 勉強するから, they can be used as the answer to both sentences but thy are plain form though. If you want to say that politely, you need to add the phrase like 勉強するので行けません.

Comment: Thx for your answer I really appreciate it! Now this might be irrelevant but how to differentiate questions which are invitational and not? Does it lie on the explanatory の particle? How if it is positive : パーティに行きますか. Is it still invitational and the same like the negative?

Comment: Invitational form are ～しませんか?, ～しよう. パーティに行きますか? is a question, which is " Do you go to the party?" in English. バーティーに行かないのですか? is a negative question, which includes the meaning like you should go to the party, "don't you go to the party?" in English.